# What is the most efficient way to push a set of changed commits in to a remote git repository?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-push

I have a remote git repository with nearly 1000 heavy commits, that is:

```
C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> ... -> C949 -> C950 -> ... -> C1000
```

Recently, I found that in commit C950, I have added large binary objects into the repo. I removed the files in my local repository using the `git filter-branch --index-filter` command. Now my local repository looks like this:

```
C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> ... -> C949 -> C1001 -> ... -> C1051
```

I know that I can undo my commits on the remote repository and then push the changes. But regarding my large commits, I want to make sure about the most efficient way to pushing my changes to the remote repository.

**Update 1:** Up to now, it is clear that I should go for a `push-force` on my remote repository. But the point is that my remote repo does not allow nonFastForward merging. Is there any other way to fix this issue?

Comment: You've already spent more time than you could possibly save.  Just force-push the new tip, if git sends some duplicate traffic it's because it'd take more time and traffic in the general case to detect it than it saves in the few cases where it could be eliminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you are attempting to rewrite some changed commits (C1001 -> .. -> C1051) into your repo that you have already pushed them before (i.e. commits C950 -> .. -> C1000), so, you have to force the push.

And regarding your FastForward configuration on the remote repo, you should have direct access to your remote repo to change the configuration.

Comment: Thanks for rebase -i

Comment: I cannot use --force-with-lease switch because from git's point of view, someone else has changed the repo and I should go for a pull first !!!

Comment: That's right. If you want to force a push when someone pushed before, git won't let you do this with the --force-with-lease. It is the normal comportment. Because if you then just --force, the others devs will loose their work, and that is not very kind :)

Answer (score 1):

If some large objects are not used by git, it will remove them automatically, and will not share them with any remote.

Just push the used references using :

```
git push origin master
```

(replace origin and master as needed with your remote and your branch).

It will only push objects and commits contained in master, this shouldn't be the case of your big commits.

Comment: I think this command will fail because my local branch repo contains commits that cannot be found on the server. The same is true for my remote repo. As a result, I think this command will fail.

Comment: The point of pushing is to transmit new objects to the server. If you mean that your history is not `fast-forward` (and thus not compatible with the current existing repository), this is the main problem with the filter-branch command. Use `git push --force` instead if you want to force the ref update.

Comment: I used 'git push --force', but this is the error message again:     remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master (you should pull first)
To https://path/to/your/url.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://path/to/your/url.git'